# regular expression for removing px from a line in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to rewrite every occurrence of something along the lines of `"height": "208px"` to `"height": 208`. The height could be different across entries,

I have been able to do it programmatically, but would like to reduce code, with a regular expression, that I've been largely unsuccessful with.
Can you help me come up with a regular expression for this?

For example:

```
"elements": [
    {
        "minHeight": 64,
        "maxHeight": 1028,
        "height": "208px",
        "minWidth": 48,
        "maxWidth": 1028,
        "defaultWidth": 512,
        "widgetid": "5892295a3ba871c00a000202"
    }
```

should be rewritten to:

```
"elements": [
    {
        "minHeight": 64,
        "maxHeight": 1028,
        "height": 208,
        "minWidth": 48,
        "maxWidth": 1028,
        "defaultWidth": 512,
        "widgetid": "5892295a3ba871c00a000202"
    }
```

Comment: @anubhava, hmm the original input does not have a px, for the maxWidth. Only the height has a "px", and that needs to be removed.

Comment: @anubhava, thanks, but as mentioned, that would remove all px. And also, it would look like, "208", as opposed to 208, the integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go for something like: `((?<=": )"(?=\d{1,4}px"))|((?<=": "\d{1,4})px")`

```
public static removePX( final String text ) {
    final String regex = "((?<=\": )\"(?=\\d{1,4}px\"))|((?<=\": \"\\d{1,4})px\")";
    return text.replaceAll( regex, "" );
}
```

This will look for `"` after `":` and before `xxxpx"` as well as `px"` after `": "xxx` and remove it.

Assuming that it is always the height field: `((?<="height": )"(?=\d{1,4}px"))|((?<="height": "\d{1,4})px")`

```
public static removePX( final String text ) {
    final String regex = "((?<=\"height\": )\"(?=\\d{1,4}px\"))|((?<=\"height\": \"\\d{1,4})px\")";
    return text.replaceAll( regex, "" );
}
```

This will look for `"` after `"height":` and before `xxxpx"` as well as `px"` after `"height": "xxx` and remove it.

`(?<=x)` is called 'lookbehind' and `(?=x)` is called 'lookahead'.

You may want to check out the Cheatsheet at [RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/) to learn more about regular expressions.
Unfortunately, the live tool supports only lookaheads but not lookbehinds.

Comment: don't completely understand how this can be used in java. Do I search for this string, and replace with what? Mind updating your response with some Java syntax?

Comment: trying this out, thanks. But since this work line by line, it would be rather slow on large files. Is it possible to replace only those lines that have something along the lines of, "height": "208px", with "height": 208,

Comment: as a unit test, I did the below, but it gave me an exception saying, "Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 10
(?<=": "\d*)px(?=")"
public String removePX( String text ) {
        
        text = "\"height\": \"208px\",";
        
        final String regex = "(?<=\": \"\\d*)px(?=\")";
        return text.replaceAll( regex, "" );
    }

Comment: this is almost great. Just that it still has the quotes, the converted string looks like this "height": "208",. I'm hoping to achieve "height": 208,

Comment: can you try with this string, and verify, it it gives the expected output? Input : text = "\"height\": \"208px\","; I get the output to be "height": ,

Comment: I was testing it out, and it looks fantastic. Thanks for helping me out, I couldn't have got a slightly complicated regex like this by myself.